# Responsive Design: Div height not updated on window resize

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

Resposive design website I'm working on.

I basically have tabbed content, with the tabs on the left (vertical) and content on the right.

I have a media query for a smaller screen size the changes the width of the content. So when the article(s) containing the content is of smaller widths, they increase in height automatically, which is to be expected and exactly what I want.

I have a script that checks height for every article, and matches all other articles to the height of the "tallest" article. (we don't want the box to resize every time someone clicks on a different tab, which is why set the height for all of them)

**Here's the Problem:**

When the resize event fires on the window, I run the same functions to calculate height and match articles to that height, but the article height returned by `$el.height();` is the same as the previous window size (before resize event fired).

Anyone know why this is?

Note that in code samples below you may notice some oddities, that's just because these snippets are part of a larger object and application.

```
function calculateHeight() {
    $el.find('article').each(function() {
        // height does not work correctly when display is none
        var elHeight = $(this).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            visibility: 'hidden',
            display: 'block'
        }).height();


        if (_height < elHeight) { _height = elHeight; }

        // Ok hide it normally again
        $(this).css({
            position: 'relative',
            visibility: 'visible',
            display: 'none'
        });

        elHeight = null;
    });
}

// resize event
$(window).resize(function() {
    /* FIXME: There is a bug here, resize is not working correctly */
    _height = 0;
    calculateHeight();
    setCalculatedSliderHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and I cannot believe I missed that. The script runs the first time, and of course it sets a manual height for all articles. Any subsequent calls on `.height()` will return that height to which is was set.

All I needed to do was change the first part of my calculateHeight() function to:

```
function calculateHeight() {
    $el.find('article').each(function() {
        // height does not work correctly when display is none
        var elHeight = $(this).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            visibility: 'hidden',
            height: 'auto',  // Reset the height
            display: 'block'
        }).height();

...
```